# JBOSS 7.1.1 Spring CXF error

Tags: spring, cxf, jboss7.x

I have a problem with one application deploy on JBOSS 7.1.1.
The application using Spring, Struts 2, JPA ...
But my problem is on Web Service deployment

My web.xml Config :

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?><web-app version="3.0" xmlns="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:schemaLocation="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee/web-app_3_0.xsd">
    <!-- ###################### SPRING ########################## -->
<context-param>
    <param-name>contextConfigLocation</param-name>
    <param-value>WEB-INF/applicationContext.xml</param-value>
</context-param>

<context-param>
    <param-name>webAppRootKey</param-name>
    <param-value>Gestionwebco-war</param-value>
</context-param>

<!-- Le listener Spring -->
<listener>
    <listener-class>org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoaderListener</listener-class>
</listener>


<!-- ###################### SPRING SECURITY ########################## -->

<!-- Filtre Spring Security -->
<filter>
    <filter-name>springSecurityFilterChain</filter-name>
    <filter-class>org.springframework.web.filter.DelegatingFilterProxy</filter-class>
</filter>

<!-- Mapping Spring Security -->
<filter-mapping>
    <filter-name>springSecurityFilterChain</filter-name>
    <url-pattern>/*</url-pattern>
</filter-mapping>

<!-- Le listener Spring security -->
<listener>
    <listener-class>org.springframework.security.web.session.HttpSessionEventPublisher</listener-class>
</listener>

<!-- ###################### ENCODING UTF-8 ########################## -->

<!-- Filtre Encoding UTF-8 -->
<filter>
    <filter-name>encodingFilter</filter-name>
    <filter-class>org.springframework.web.filter.CharacterEncodingFilter</filter-class>
    <init-param>
        <param-name>encoding</param-name>
        <param-value>UTF-8</param-value>
    </init-param>
    <init-param>
        <param-name>forceEncoding</param-name>
        <param-value>true</param-value>
    </init-param>
</filter>
<!-- Mapping du filtre encoding -->
<filter-mapping>
    <filter-name>encodingFilter</filter-name>
    <url-pattern>/*</url-pattern>
</filter-mapping>
```

My Jboss-deployment.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?><jboss-deployment-structure>
<deployment>
    <dependencies>
        <module name="org.springframework.spring" slot="snowdrop">
            <imports>
                <include path="META-INF**" />
                <include path="org**" />
            </imports>
        </module>
        <module name="org.apache.cxf">
            <imports>
                <include path="**"/>
            </imports>
        </module>
    </dependencies>
</deployment>
```

My application-context.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?><beans xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans"
xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns:jaxws="http://cxf.apache.org/jaxws"
xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans-2.5.xsd http://cxf.apache.org/jaxws http://cxf.apache.org/schemas/jaxws.xsd">  
<import resource="classpath:META-INF/cxf/cxf.xml" />
<import resource="classpath:META-INF/cxf/cxf-servlet.xml" />

<import resource="classpath:spring-dao.xml" />

<import resource="classpath:spring-process.xml" />

<import resource="classpath:spring-web.xml" />

<import resource="classpath:spring-security.xml"/>

<jaxws:endpoint id="testServiceEndPoint" implementor="#testService" address="/TestService" />
```

My spring-web.xml

```
<bean id="testService" class="services.impl.TestService"></bean>
```

My Interface :

```
package services;import javax.jws.WebMethod;
import javax.jws.WebParam;
import javax.jws.WebResult;
import javax.jws.WebService;
@WebService(name = "TestService", targetNamespace = "http://localhost:8080/gestion/")
public interface ITestService {
    @WebMethod
    @WebResult(name = "reponse")
    public abstract String getNom(@WebParam(name = "nom") String nom);
}
```

And my impl :

```
package services.impl;
import javax.jws.WebService;
import org.springframework.transaction.annotation.Transactional;
import services.ITestService;
@WebService(endpointInterface = "services.ITestService", targetNamespace = "http://localhost:8080/gestion/")
@Transactional(timeout = 1800)
public class TestService implements ITestService {
    public String getNom(String nom) {
        return "Salut "+nom;
    }
}
```

And JBOSS log :

```
15:20:59,472 WARN  [org.jboss.modules] (MSC service thread 1-5) Failed to define class org.apache.cxf.jaxws.spring.NamespaceHandler in Module "org.apache.cxf:main" from local module loader @6564dbd5 (roots: /Users/mowmow/Documents/Projet pro/jboss-as-7.1.1.Final/modules): java.lang.LinkageError: Failed to link org/apache/cxf/jaxws/spring/NamespaceHandler (Module "org.apache.cxf:main" from local module loader @6564dbd5 (roots: /Users/mowmow/Documents/Projet pro/jboss-as-7.1.1.Final/modules))
at org.jboss.modules.ModuleClassLoader.defineClass(ModuleClassLoader.java:396)
at org.jboss.modules.ModuleClassLoader.loadClassLocal(ModuleClassLoader.java:243)
at org.jboss.modules.ModuleClassLoader$1.loadClassLocal(ModuleClassLoader.java:73)
at org.jboss.modules.Module.loadModuleClass(Module.java:517)
at org.jboss.modules.ModuleClassLoader.findClass(ModuleClassLoader.java:182)
at org.jboss.modules.ConcurrentClassLoader.performLoadClassUnchecked(ConcurrentClassLoader.java:468)
at org.jboss.modules.ConcurrentClassLoader.performLoadClassChecked(ConcurrentClassLoader.java:456)
at org.jboss.modules.ConcurrentClassLoader.performLoadClass(ConcurrentClassLoader.java:398)
at org.jboss.modules.ConcurrentClassLoader.loadClass(ConcurrentClassLoader.java:120)
at org.springframework.util.ClassUtils.forName(ClassUtils.java:258) [spring-core.jar:3.1.4.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.beans.factory.xml.DefaultNamespaceHandlerResolver.resolve(DefaultNamespaceHandlerResolver.java:124) [spring-beans.jar:3.1.4.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.beans.factory.xml.BeanDefinitionParserDelegate.parseCustomElement(BeanDefinitionParserDelegate.java:1418) [spring-beans.jar:3.1.4.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.beans.factory.xml.BeanDefinitionParserDelegate.parseCustomElement(BeanDefinitionParserDelegate.java:1413) [spring-beans.jar:3.1.4.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.beans.factory.xml.DefaultBeanDefinitionDocumentReader.parseBeanDefinitions(DefaultBeanDefinitionDocumentReader.java:184) [spring-beans.jar:3.1.4.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.beans.factory.xml.DefaultBeanDefinitionDocumentReader.doRegisterBeanDefinitions(DefaultBeanDefinitionDocumentReader.java:140) [spring-beans.jar:3.1.4.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.beans.factory.xml.DefaultBeanDefinitionDocumentReader.registerBeanDefinitions(DefaultBeanDefinitionDocumentReader.java:111) [spring-beans.jar:3.1.4.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.beans.factory.xml.XmlBeanDefinitionReader.registerBeanDefinitions(XmlBeanDefinitionReader.java:493) [spring-beans.jar:3.1.4.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.beans.factory.xml.XmlBeanDefinitionReader.doLoadBeanDefinitions(XmlBeanDefinitionReader.java:390) [spring-beans.jar:3.1.4.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.beans.factory.xml.XmlBeanDefinitionReader.loadBeanDefinitions(XmlBeanDefinitionReader.java:334) [spring-beans.jar:3.1.4.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.beans.factory.xml.XmlBeanDefinitionReader.loadBeanDefinitions(XmlBeanDefinitionReader.java:302) [spring-beans.jar:3.1.4.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanDefinitionReader.loadBeanDefinitions(AbstractBeanDefinitionReader.java:174) [spring-beans.jar:3.1.4.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanDefinitionReader.loadBeanDefinitions(AbstractBeanDefinitionReader.java:209) [spring-beans.jar:3.1.4.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanDefinitionReader.loadBeanDefinitions(AbstractBeanDefinitionReader.java:180) [spring-beans.jar:3.1.4.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.web.context.support.XmlWebApplicationContext.loadBeanDefinitions(XmlWebApplicationContext.java:125) [spring-web.jar:3.1.4.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.web.context.support.XmlWebApplicationContext.loadBeanDefinitions(XmlWebApplicationContext.java:94) [spring-web.jar:3.1.4.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractRefreshableApplicationContext.refreshBeanFactory(AbstractRefreshableApplicationContext.java:131) [spring-context.jar:3.1.4.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.obtainFreshBeanFactory(AbstractApplicationContext.java:530) [spring-context.jar:3.1.4.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.refresh(AbstractApplicationContext.java:444) [spring-context.jar:3.1.4.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoader.configureAndRefreshWebApplicationContext(ContextLoader.java:388) [spring-web.jar:3.1.4.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoader.initWebApplicationContext(ContextLoader.java:293) [spring-web.jar:3.1.4.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoaderListener.contextInitialized(ContextLoaderListener.java:111) [spring-web.jar:3.1.4.RELEASE]
at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext.contextListenerStart(StandardContext.java:3392) [jbossweb-7.0.13.Final.jar:]
at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext.start(StandardContext.java:3850) [jbossweb-7.0.13.Final.jar:]
at org.jboss.as.web.deployment.WebDeploymentService.start(WebDeploymentService.java:90) [jboss-as-web-7.1.1.Final.jar:7.1.1.Final]
at org.jboss.msc.service.ServiceControllerImpl$StartTask.startService(ServiceControllerImpl.java:1811)
at org.jboss.msc.service.ServiceControllerImpl$StartTask.run(ServiceControllerImpl.java:1746)
at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.runTask(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:895) [classes.jar:1.6.0_65]
at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:918) [classes.jar:1.6.0_65]
at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:695) [classes.jar:1.6.0_65]Caused by: java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: org/springframework/beans/factory/xml/NamespaceHandlerSupport
at java.lang.ClassLoader.defineClass1(Native Method) [classes.jar:1.6.0_65]
at java.lang.ClassLoader.defineClassCond(ClassLoader.java:637) [classes.jar:1.6.0_65]
at java.lang.ClassLoader.defineClass(ClassLoader.java:621) [classes.jar:1.6.0_65]
at java.security.SecureClassLoader.defineClass(SecureClassLoader.java:141) [classes.jar:1.6.0_65]
at org.jboss.modules.ModuleClassLoader.doDefineOrLoadClass(ModuleClassLoader.java:327)
at org.jboss.modules.ModuleClassLoader.defineClass(ModuleClassLoader.java:391)
... 38 moreCaused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: org.springframework.beans.factory.xml.NamespaceHandlerSupport from [Module "org.apache.cxf:main" from local module loader @6564dbd5 (roots: /Users/mowmow/Documents/Projet pro/jboss-as-7.1.1.Final/modules)]
at org.jboss.modules.ModuleClassLoader.findClass(ModuleClassLoader.java:190)
at org.jboss.modules.ConcurrentClassLoader.performLoadClassUnchecked(ConcurrentClassLoader.java:468)
at org.jboss.modules.ConcurrentClassLoader.performLoadClassChecked(ConcurrentClassLoader.java:456)
at org.jboss.modules.ConcurrentClassLoader.performLoadClassChecked(ConcurrentClassLoader.java:423)
at org.jboss.modules.ConcurrentClassLoader.performLoadClass(ConcurrentClassLoader.java:398)
at org.jboss.modules.ConcurrentClassLoader.loadClass(ConcurrentClassLoader.java:120)
... 44 more 15:20:59,488 ERROR [org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoader] (MSC service thread 1-5) Context initialization failed: org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanDefinitionStoreException: Unexpected exception parsing XML document from ServletContext resource [/WEB-INF/applicationContext.xml]; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.FatalBeanException: NamespaceHandler class [org.apache.cxf.jaxws.spring.NamespaceHandler] for namespace [http://cxf.apache.org/jaxws] not found; nested exception is java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: org.apache.cxf.jaxws.spring.NamespaceHandler from [Module "deployment.Gestion-web-co-web.war:main" from Service Module Loader]
at org.springframework.beans.factory.xml.XmlBeanDefinitionReader.doLoadBeanDefinitions(XmlBeanDefinitionReader.java:412) [spring-beans.jar:3.1.4.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.beans.factory.xml.XmlBeanDefinitionReader.loadBeanDefinitions(XmlBeanDefinitionReader.java:334) [spring-beans.jar:3.1.4.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.beans.factory.xml.XmlBeanDefinitionReader.loadBeanDefinitions(XmlBeanDefinitionReader.java:302) [spring-beans.jar:3.1.4.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanDefinitionReader.loadBeanDefinitions(AbstractBeanDefinitionReader.java:174) [spring-beans.jar:3.1.4.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanDefinitionReader.loadBeanDefinitions(AbstractBeanDefinitionReader.java:209) [spring-beans.jar:3.1.4.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanDefinitionReader.loadBeanDefinitions(AbstractBeanDefinitionReader.java:180) [spring-beans.jar:3.1.4.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.web.context.support.XmlWebApplicationContext.loadBeanDefinitions(XmlWebApplicationContext.java:125) [spring-web.jar:3.1.4.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.web.context.support.XmlWebApplicationContext.loadBeanDefinitions(XmlWebApplicationContext.java:94) [spring-web.jar:3.1.4.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractRefreshableApplicationContext.refreshBeanFactory(AbstractRefreshableApplicationContext.java:131) [spring-context.jar:3.1.4.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.obtainFreshBeanFactory(AbstractApplicationContext.java:530) [spring-context.jar:3.1.4.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.refresh(AbstractApplicationContext.java:444) [spring-context.jar:3.1.4.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoader.configureAndRefreshWebApplicationContext(ContextLoader.java:388) [spring-web.jar:3.1.4.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoader.initWebApplicationContext(ContextLoader.java:293) [spring-web.jar:3.1.4.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoaderListener.contextInitialized(ContextLoaderListener.java:111) [spring-web.jar:3.1.4.RELEASE]
at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext.contextListenerStart(StandardContext.java:3392) [jbossweb-7.0.13.Final.jar:]
at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext.start(StandardContext.java:3850) [jbossweb-7.0.13.Final.jar:]
at org.jboss.as.web.deployment.WebDeploymentService.start(WebDeploymentService.java:90) [jboss-as-web-7.1.1.Final.jar:7.1.1.Final]
at org.jboss.msc.service.ServiceControllerImpl$StartTask.startService(ServiceControllerImpl.java:1811)
at org.jboss.msc.service.ServiceControllerImpl$StartTask.run(ServiceControllerImpl.java:1746)
at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.runTask(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:895) [classes.jar:1.6.0_65]
at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:918) [classes.jar:1.6.0_65]
at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:695) [classes.jar:1.6.0_65]Caused by: org.springframework.beans.FatalBeanException: NamespaceHandler class [org.apache.cxf.jaxws.spring.NamespaceHandler] for namespace [http://cxf.apache.org/jaxws] not found; nested exception is java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: org.apache.cxf.jaxws.spring.NamespaceHandler from [Module "deployment.Gestion-web-co-web.war:main" from Service Module Loader]
at org.springframework.beans.factory.xml.DefaultNamespaceHandlerResolver.resolve(DefaultNamespaceHandlerResolver.java:135) [spring-beans.jar:3.1.4.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.beans.factory.xml.BeanDefinitionParserDelegate.parseCustomElement(BeanDefinitionParserDelegate.java:1418) [spring-beans.jar:3.1.4.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.beans.factory.xml.BeanDefinitionParserDelegate.parseCustomElement(BeanDefinitionParserDelegate.java:1413) [spring-beans.jar:3.1.4.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.beans.factory.xml.DefaultBeanDefinitionDocumentReader.parseBeanDefinitions(DefaultBeanDefinitionDocumentReader.java:184) [spring-beans.jar:3.1.4.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.beans.factory.xml.DefaultBeanDefinitionDocumentReader.doRegisterBeanDefinitions(DefaultBeanDefinitionDocumentReader.java:140) [spring-beans.jar:3.1.4.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.beans.factory.xml.DefaultBeanDefinitionDocumentReader.registerBeanDefinitions(DefaultBeanDefinitionDocumentReader.java:111) [spring-beans.jar:3.1.4.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.beans.factory.xml.XmlBeanDefinitionReader.registerBeanDefinitions(XmlBeanDefinitionReader.java:493) [spring-beans.jar:3.1.4.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.beans.factory.xml.XmlBeanDefinitionReader.doLoadBeanDefinitions(XmlBeanDefinitionReader.java:390) [spring-beans.jar:3.1.4.RELEASE]
... 21 moreCaused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: org.apache.cxf.jaxws.spring.NamespaceHandler from [Module "deployment.Gestion-web-co-web.war:main" from Service Module Loader]
at org.jboss.modules.ModuleClassLoader.findClass(ModuleClassLoader.java:190)
at org.jboss.modules.ConcurrentClassLoader.performLoadClassUnchecked(ConcurrentClassLoader.java:468)
at org.jboss.modules.ConcurrentClassLoader.performLoadClassChecked(ConcurrentClassLoader.java:456)
at org.jboss.modules.ConcurrentClassLoader.performLoadClass(ConcurrentClassLoader.java:398)
at org.jboss.modules.ConcurrentClassLoader.loadClass(ConcurrentClassLoader.java:120)
at org.springframework.util.ClassUtils.forName(ClassUtils.java:258) [spring-core.jar:3.1.4.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.beans.factory.xml.DefaultNamespaceHandlerResolver.resolve(DefaultNamespaceHandlerResolver.java:124) [spring-beans.jar:3.1.4.RELEASE]
... 28 more
```

Any solution ?

Answer (score 0):

Looks like you miss the `cxf-bundle-<version>.jar` in your classpath. Download and add it.

That jar contains the class `org.apache.cxf.jaxws.spring.NamespaceHandler` wich is missing`

> ... 21 moreCaused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: org.apache.cxf.jaxws.spring.NamespaceHandler from [Module "deployment.Gestion-web-co-web.war:main" from Service Module Loader]

Comment: it is not supposed to use that of jboss modules ?

Answer (score 0):

The solution is to put spring into a JBOSS module and add a dependency to spring in the org.apache.cf